# Task runner is not running on my local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-data-pipeline, runner

I am running task runner to perform the defined task, while running it am getting exception telling that can't upload log files to s3. After debugging the task runner application I found that, it will use ACL option to upload task runner log files to S3, due to some restrictions I should not use ACL option while uploading files to S3.

Please suggest if I can do anything to resolve this without configuring ACL on objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the computational resource owner cannot have write permissions on the S3 log path? You will need to give write permissions on the log path (through ACLs)if you want task runner to upload the logs automatically to S3.

If you don't want to push the task runner log files to S3, you can disable logging by not specifying "logUri" while starting the task runner. In that case, task runner will not try to upload the log files and should not fail.

Comment: Even after ignoring logUri attribute it is giving access denied exception in task runner logs due to the ACL permissions, but the task is getting completed. Is there any way where we can ignore the ACL option or any way to avoid the exception.